# Chef: how to recursively delete all files while keeping certain files

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a folder structure like this:

```
/app
    /uploads
        1.pdf
        2.pdf
        /2015
        /2016
        /2017
        ......
    /requirements
    /tests
    manage.py
    ......
```

I used to recursively delete the `app` dictionary. Now I'd like to keep all the folds and files in them in `uploads`, eg. `/2015`, `/2016`, `/2016/oct.pdf`. Also, delete `1.pdf` and `2.pdf`.

```
# remove the code folder if exists
directory node['conf-cookbook']['app_dir'] do
   recursive true
   action :delete
   only_if { ::File.directory?("#{ PATH }") }
end
```

How do I construct guards to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something the directory resource can do. Guard clauses control if the whole resource activates or doesn't, they aren't a line-item veto during converge. You would need to make a custom resource, or just use something like `execute "find #{node['conf-cookbook']['app_dir']} -somefilter -delete"` and not care that it isn't idempotent.